# My html file is not pulling in the correct css file...Why is this?

Tags: html, css

In my html file, I am pulling in main.css by linking it...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
```

However, whenever I open the html file in firefox, it pulls in an older version of the file. Yes...I checked whether or not there were two versions of the file in my root directory - there aren't. There is not another main.css file in any directories. How is it possible that the computer is pulling in an old version of the file and not updating when I save the new css file?

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache, closing the browser and then re-opening it to show the same website?

Answer (score 2):

Use "Ctrl + R" after loading the site

Answer (score 2):

Browsers cache files and stores copies of the files locally in order to make it faster.

I don't know how you are hosting the file. If caching is the problem, press CTRL+F5 or CTRl+R to refresh the cache.

Comment: Thanks! I know this is super basic, but quite frustrating.